# Using select on JSON field in Sequeilze

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'd like to find some items, but return only one field (`name`) from a JSON field (`body`). The JSON field is also in an association (`Version`), if that matters.

I *imagine* it would be something like this.

```
Part.findAll({
  attributes: ['slug'],
  include : [{
    model: Version,
    limit: 1,
    order: [['createdAt', 'DESC']],
    attributes: ['body.name']
  }]
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to write a comment but I can't because I don't have enough reputation. So can't you just retrieve the body and from the results, get the required attributes of the JSON.

Comment: Sending some reputation your way.